# ArcGIS Editor Attributes Dialog in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, editing

Is there a way to update the Editor Attributes dialog to populate/refresh on ArcObject feature selection code?  The attributes dialog only seems to respond to a manual view selection or manual table selection.  Here is my current feature selection code:

```
Try

            Dim pFeatSelection As IFeatureSelection = Nothing
            Dim pFeatureLayer As IFeatureLayer
            Dim pQueryFilter As IQueryFilter
            Dim pSelSet As ISelectionSet
            Dim pFCur As IFeatureCursor = Nothing
            Dim player As ILayer
            Dim pEnumLayer As IEnumLayer

            m_App = CType(Hook, IApplication)
            m_MxDoc = CType(m_App.Document, IMxDocument)
            m_mxDocument = CType(m_App.Document, MxDocument)
            m_map = CType(m_MxDoc.FocusMap, Map)

            Dim pActiveView As IActiveView
            pActiveView = m_MxDoc.FocusMap

            m_map = m_MxDoc.ActiveView.FocusMap
            pEnumLayer = m_map.Layers

            Dim number As Int32 = InputBox("FID number")

            player = pEnumLayer.Next
            Do Until player Is Nothing
                If player.Name = "MyLayer" Then
                    pFeatureLayer = CType(player, IFeatureLayer)
                    pFeatSelection = CType(pFeatureLayer, IFeatureSelection)
                End If
                player = pEnumLayer.Next
            Loop

            pQueryFilter = New QueryFilter
            pQueryFilter.WhereClause = "FID = " & number

            pActiveView.PartialRefresh(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGeoSelection, Nothing, Nothing)

            pFeatSelection.SelectFeatures(pQueryFilter, esriSelectionResultEnum.esriSelectionResultNew, False)
            ' Create a feature cursor of selected interstates.
            pSelSet = pFeatSelection.SelectionSet
            pSelSet.Search(Nothing, False, pFCur)
            pActiveView.PartialRefresh(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGeoSelection, Nothing, Nothing)

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Caught an unspecified error in the calling code: " & vbCrLf & ex.ToString)
        Finally
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you call [IFeatureSelection.SelectionChanged](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/0012/0012000004z6000000.htm) on every layer you update the selection of.

Also, while not needed in every case, once the layer selection is updated for all desired layers, you should cast the [Map](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/MapClass_Class/001200000s13000000/) to [ISelectionEvents](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ISelectionEvents_Interface/001200000qn6000000/) and call [ISelectionEvents.SelectionChanged](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/0012/001200000qn7000000.htm) as well.